# Invalid Siri Support - Warning iTunes Connect

Tags: ios10, nslocalizedstring, sirikit

I'm integrate SiriKit in my app for ride a book but after send my app to TestFlight I get a mail response with the next warnings.

> Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for
>   INGetRideStatusIntent in the "en-CO" language
>
> Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for
>   INRequestRideIntent in the "en" language

I have added the necessary translation to my InfoPlist.string for each localised version but the problem still happens.

I'm using the AppIntentVocabulary.plist where I added examples phrases for `INGetRideStatusIntent and INRequestRideIntent`

In the apple documentation for localized plist file, say that I should add key="value for localized string" but in this case in `AppIntentVocabulary.plist` no have a key I have a Array and I don`t know how to write the correct localized string in InfoPlist.string.

e.g.

> CFBundleDisplayName = "Maisons"; NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright
>   © 2014 My Great Company Tous droits réservés.";

somebody know how can solve this warnings ?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem, the solution is very simple, the only thing that I need to do is add Localized option to `AppIntentVocabulary.plist`.

- In Xcode, select the `AppIntentVocabulary`
- In inspector panel click on the `Localized` button
- Select all languages needed to support
- Add corresponding translation to `Example Phrases` and that's all.

Comment: Were you able to get Siri to be enabled and working if you are installing it via Testflight? I was able to get it to run correctly if using Xcode to run it but not in Testflight, even though my app is toggled on in Settings > Siri > App Support

Comment: @jasonnoahchoi I have the same problem. Shows up if I run fro Xcode but does not show up via TestFlight. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Should this file be added to the main app or to the Intent target?

Comment: Add this files to the main app.

Comment: Did you guys ever solve this? All my deliveries (although successful) still give, Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for INSearchForPhotosIntent in the "en" language

Answer (score 0):

I got that comment for EN when I submitted a build to the App Store, and English is my system language! After lots of experiments, what worked was to select the AppIntentVocabulary.plist file, and in the Inspector pane (where I assume you've selected Localize), also check the English box.

For several other files – Intents.intentdefinition, LaunchScreen.storyboard, Main.storyboard – I have not had to also check the English box. It was implicit in the Base localization. But for .strings, the English box is to be checked and there is no Base.

With AppIntentVocabulary.plist, there's a Base and an English, and they both need to be checked.

I don't know why there's that inconsistency, and I don't know if there's a better way. I just know this configuration kept me from receiving those App Store Connect warnings.