# Siri Intent Example Phrase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, siri, sirikit

When I upload my app to iTunes Connect with the new Siri Intents I receive a message saying:

```
Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for INSetMessageAttributeIntent in the "en" language

Invalid Siri Support - No example phrase was provided for INSendMessageIntent in the "en" language
```

I have created a `AppIntentVocabulary.plist` in the main App and Localized it but keep receiving this issue every time I upload.

Is the file in the incorrect place or am I putting these example phrases in the wrong place?

Thanks

Comment: I opened a ticket with Apple Developer Technical Support and they said it was a bug and that I should file it.

Comment: @rocky Okay. I have also contacted them and have sent over the file. Let me know when you file the bug and I'll let them know I have this issue too. Thanks!

Comment: OK. So it seems that localizing the AppIntentVocabulary.plist file causes the bug. Try deleting the localized versions and see what happens.

Comment: I got that comment for EN when I submitted a build to the App Store, and English is my system language! I posted an answer that solved this problem for me at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373696/invalid-siri-support-warning-itunes-connect/52159606#52159606